# Monotouch 6.0.6 and XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xcode4.5

I've been using MonoTouch 6.0.6 and xCode 4.2 for a while and everything was good. Recently one requirement came for which I had to use iOS6 SDK. I downloaded Xcode 4.5 dmg file from app dev centre. When I try to install, its just an app so it doesn't install. I want my Monotouch to use Xcode 4.5, how do I do? I am stuck on this and not able to find the solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Here is what I did -

a. Opening the DMG file, it mounted on a drive and kept on desktop.

b. Click on the XCode on the mounted drive opened XCode, so I copied the XCode.app to application folder

c. In Monotouch, under preferences-> SdK Location, select the Application/Xcode.app as the apple sdk.

Using this, Monotouch picks up the new SDK and start using iOS6 simulator.

Comment: MonoTouch support also confirmed the same steps!

Answer (score 1):

You should just drag the app from the .DMG into your Applications folder, open it, and then it'll handle the rest. Monotouch will then use Xcode 4.5.

Comment: Thanks! Dragging did the trick but I had to set the SDK location in Monotouch to the new Xcode.app to get it working.